# Always an extra row at the end of the HTML table when imported from CSV

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm always getting an extra row at the end of the table when I'm importing the table data from CSV file using Java script.

Java script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.1.2/papaparse.js"></script>
<script>
    function arrayToTable(tableData) {
        var table = $('<table></table>');

        $(tableData).each(function (i, rowData) {
            var row = $('<tr></tr>');
            $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
                row.append($('<td>'+cellData+'</td>'));
            });
            table.append(row);
        });

        return table;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./1.csv",
        success: function (data) {
            $('body').append(arrayToTable(Papa.parse(data).data));
        }
    });
</script>
```

Table data:

```
name      marks
asab      7
bahcv     5
cdsv      5
fdasv     6
```

Output I'm getting:

[image]

I checked the value of i and j in the script and found that the value if i start from 0 and goes by the total number of rows;

```
document.write("i=",i,'<br>');
```

[image]

Because of this probably I'm getting an extra row. How to get rid of this extra row? what should I change in the script.

Comment: Have you tried printing out ```Papa.parse(data).data``` to see what exactly you're putting into the function? It could be that's where an extra line is added.

Comment: but the variable `rowData` should be completly empty then, can you not just check for that?

Comment: It could be a quirk of csv passing an empty row, it could be js phrasing it that way. Without live code, will be hard to debug. However, why don't you check if there is any data before you append the new row, should do the trick.

Comment: As @René says, I think you could also just check ```if (rowData != []) {// code}``` or ```if (rowData != ['', '', '']) {// code}```, whichever it is

Comment: no, `if (!rowData) return` if it's the last one `['', '', '']` then you maybe have to much line endings in your source cvs, but i guess it's empty, so, just  `if (!rowData) return`

Comment: Or you _could_ just read the documentation for the parser library you are using there … and discover that it offers a configuration option named `skipEmptyLines` already. https://www.papaparse.com/docs#config

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. 
$('body').append(arrayToTable(Papa.parse(data, {skipEmptyLines: true}).data));